# Java 8 collect to Map<String, List<Object>>

Tags: java, java-8

I have two object. The first one:

```
public final class Object1 {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    // constructor getter and setter
}
```

The second one:

```
public class Object2 {
    private BigDecimal value1;
    private BigDecimal value2;
    // constructor getter and setter
}
```

I have a `Map<Object1, Object2>`:

```
    Object1{a="15", b="XXX"}, Object2{value1=12.1, value2=32.3}
    Object1{a="15", b="YYY"}, Object2{value1=21.1, value2=24.3}
    Object1{a="16", b="AAA"}, Object2{value1=34.1, value2=45.3}
    Object1{a="15", b="BBB"}, Object2{value1=23.1, value2=65.3}
    Object1{a="15", b="DDD"}, Object2{value1=23.1, value2=67.3}
    Object1{a="17", b="CCC"}, Object2{value1=78.1, value2=2.3}
........
```

I want to group this map with the same a in a list of Object2 like:

```
a="15", {{value1=12.1, value2=32.3}, {value1=21.1, value2=24.3}, {value1=23.1, value2=65.3}, {value1=23.1, value2=67.3}},
a="16", {{value1=34.1, value2=45.3}}
...
```

I try something like this:

```
Map<String, List<Object2>> map1 = map.entrySet()
   .stream()             
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey().getA(), list of object with this key);
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
yourMap.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey().getA(),
               Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())))
```

Comment: How can i group this map with the same 'a' and the mean value of all value1 in the list of object2 in a collect statement? Something like a="15", mean value of Object2.value1,
a="16", mean value of Object2.value1

Comment: @emoleumassi so basically u want a `Map<String, BigDecimal>` where value is the `min` from all those `value1`?

Comment: yes. a Map<String, BigDecimal> where value is the min from all those value1

Comment: @emoleumassi `map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getKey().getA(),
                        Collectors.mapping(x -> x.getValue().getValue1(),
                                Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                                        Collectors.minBy(
                                                Comparator.naturalOrder()),
                                        Optional::get))))`

Comment: @Eugene or just `map.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getKey().getA(), x -> x.getValue().getValue1(), BigDecimal::min))`, which is quite shorter

Comment: @Eugene just in case, test it (I'm at the phone at the slowest bus of the country)...